# How to access two different values for one checkbox?

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, form-submit

I'm using HTML, PHP, jQuery for my website.
I've a check box on my form as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check_status" id="check_status" value="1"> Status
```

I want the same check box for two different values. In short, after submission of the form if check box is checked I should get the value 1 in `$_POST['check_status']` array and if the check box is unchecked at the time of submission of form I should get the value as 0 in `$_POST['check_status']` array after form submission.

Now as per the above HTML code if check box is checked I'm getting value 1 and if the check box is unchecked then I'm getting blank value.

How should I resolve this issue to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Why can't you consider checkbox is unchecked as it equals `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add condition in php. Hope this will help.

```
if(isset($_POST['check_status'])) {
    $status = $_POST['check_status'];
} else {
    $status = 0;
}

echo $status;
```

Comment: Why to write 4 lines of code when you can reduce it to only 1 line? `$status = isset($_POST['check_status']) ? $_POST['check_status'] : 0;`

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
$status = 0;
if(isset($_POST['check_status'])) {
    $status = 1;
}

echo $status;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you really need those values to be send as `1` and `0` to the server ( maybe you can't change the server-side code), you can add a hidden field with the same name as your checkbox, and then use `JavaScript/jQuery` to fill that hidden field, before you submit the form, with 1 or 0, for checkbox being checked, respectively unchecked. .

```
$("#hiddenField").val( $('#checkbox').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0 );
```